# Using single or double quote

Tags: editing, proofreading

I have scoured the internet but have found conflicting information. When in in dialogue in writing a person mentions the name of a song, should it be in single quote? Example below and the part in question is the title of the song, Dance With My Father Again:

She pushed the play button on the remote and the soulful voice of Luther Vandross singing, ‘Dance with my Father Again,’ filled the room.

This makes me think of something else; being that it's a title, should every beginning word be capitalized = Dance With My Father Again?

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 1):

Song titles belong in quotes.  If you're writing fiction think about the reader.  Dialog uses double-quotes to frame the spoken word.  In that dialog a song title can't also use double-quotes without potentially confusing the reader about where the dialog ends. So that is a good time to use single quotes.

"My favorite song," she said, "is 'Memories', or maybe 'All of Me', or even 'Hello'."

Hope this helps.

Comment: Either that (standard American style), or exactly the opposite (typical British or Australian style).